# How to customize, Business Node Selector in Cluster Environment?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, cluster-computing

I do not want to rely on default algorithm of business cluster for selecting nodes.
How to write code to select a active business node in JBoss.

```java
String findAndSelectActiveNode(List<String> allNodes) {
      // do some logic
      return "an-active-node-logical-name";
}
```

Need similar code like this.

Node selector code should select an active node randomly.